# PDI aka Kettle : is better "add constant" or "literal string" in table input?

Tags: kettle, pdi

In a Kettle/ PDI transformation, I need to write on a table the values from another table plus other static strings.

1 Table input : read records;

2 Add constants : add "status" = "A"; (and other static strings)

3 Table output : write old values + status and other constants

Is it better to add the literal in the table input "select" (select id,field1, 'A' as status from ...) or better to use an Add Constants step?

I suppose it's better to reduce steps' quantity, because with "Add constants" 
 you need to instantiate a new step.

EDIT: For "better" I mean faster and less memory consuming

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to make the minimum transformation on the `Input Table` step, because the philosophy of the PDI is to make visible all the transformation.

Now, if you're an expert in SQL, or have a legacy select of 200 lines with complex computation, my answer would be different.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I did't write what "better" mean for me. I need to read about million records, so i want to use less memory and less time

Answer (score 0):

Creating one more step in transformation will lead to separate thread allocation since every step is separate thread as far as allocation of at least one BlockingQueue since rows between steps is distributed in memory through these structures.

Using one more step even so simple as add constant will cause additional resource allocations.

PDI is still happy to be open source.

If you curious how it is done this is base transformation step implementation (was for long time) -> https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/trans/step/BaseStep.java

This is example of code used to distribute rows between steps -> https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/core/BlockingRowSet.java#L54

Sure for simple add constant in sql query PDI will be overhead. There is a lot of use-cases how to make some operations faster or less memory consuming, but about GUI or any other feature actually PDI is famous of?

Comment: It is not because you add a step and a thread that the program will run slower. I have case in which it was, on the contrary, quicker. The basic idea is that that the PDI can process the rows already in memory while still waiting for the database to push record on the internet.

Comment: ...database can process it's own tuples just in place even more efficient, also in memory, just send constant value as select/update statement and you don't need to fetch all rows via internet, just send only constant value instead.Regular programming languages or even scripts gives much more flexibility of data processing, disadvantage only it quickly becomes complex.

Comment: That's not always true. I have cases where the SQL query is 1/2h while the spoon, is a matter of minutes. Admittedly, the SQL was particularity long and badly written, so the engine could not optimize it.

Comment: I disagree also that regular programming languages or scripts gives much more flexibility of data processing. Kettle is a dataflow programming language (I am talking about the java underlying program, not the GUI), and there is nothing better for data processing. In facts, databases uses the same paradigm, with the difference that you do not control the optimization step. So my philosophy: do every thing in PDI and keep the ionput queries as simple as possible (with the exception of sorting).

Comment: I can review any solution designed with Kettle and I am sure I will find a way to do it more efficiently with raw java and modern systems, starting from regular java 8 streaming up to distributed computing with apache storm / hazelcast DAG. My opinion once again is that kettle is great for GUI ability. All other is arguable, especially back-end implementation. Even not start to talk how is big-data-plugin is designed under the hood. I would appreciate if you give me any close-to-real example. Thank you.

Comment: The real example cannot fit in this 600 character comment window. The smaller case was a 2000 line sql, with 8 levels of joins on select and cases copy/pasted many time. The data extraction was taking 3-4 hours on a dedicated SAP-Hana columnar db. Simply by rewriting it in clean programming with Kettle, the extract did run in minutes. I don't think the GUI helped me much, but using a dataflow driven approach certainly did. It is relatively easy to fool an algorithm by putting near its worse case. It is much difficult to do the same for an experienced human brain.